# Connecting to Socket over TCP but server is not receiving it

Tags: sockets, tls1.2

I'm attempting to connect to a socket connection and post a 'login' command but the server doesn't seem to be receiving my command.

I would provide the hostname but it's IP restricted so I don't believe that would provide you any benefit.

```
import socket
import ssl
import os

hostname = 'example.hostname.come'
context = ssl.create_default_context()
loginCommand = 'login username password'

# Create a client socket
socketInstance = socket.socket();

# Get an instance of SSLSocket
sslSocketInstance = context.wrap_socket(socketInstance, server_hostname=hostname);
sslSocketInstance.connect((hostname, 14555));
# Connect to a server

# Send Login Details
print('Sending Message');
sslSocketInstance.sendall(loginCommand.encode());
print('Message Sent');

# Receive Response
print('Checking Response');
received = sslSocketInstance.recv(1024);
print('Response Received');
print(received.decode());
```

The server is then times out after 1 minute (as stated in the documentation) and returns:
`ERR no login message received`. This is the servers errors message so I am connecting and can retrieve just not send my message.

I have attempted a few different approached like adding a `socket.listen(1)` but I was never able to get this working. This was the only approach which I was able to receive a response from the server. I have also attempted `socket.send(data)` but same response.

Also important to note the request must be wrapped in TLS when creating the socket connection. I assume this is done when I complete `wrap_socket`.

Apologies for my noobness regard everything sockets.

Comment: Should your login command have a line terminator?

Comment: Hi, the documentation doesn't specify but I added a ```CR``` and not luck

Comment: Try CRLF or LF. There must be something to tell the server where the command ends. Should there be a length word prefix?

Comment: Hmm, I've attempted all these but no luck (CRLF, LF, CR, CR+LF). The documentation does say this regarding it: ```Request a message or range of messages from the Data Feed server. (Also sets the server's end-of-line sequence to CR+LF rather than CR; see the REQ command below.) ``` Not sure if this helps

Answer (score 0):

With help from @user207421, I was able to determine that I needed a line terminator.
I added a \n to the send of my request and this successfully returned.

Comment: Well LF is `\n` and you said you tried that.